# How do I split a number grid into rectangular polygons?

Tags: geometry, polygons

I am starting with a grid of numbers of a similar format to this:

```
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,9,9,9,1,1,1,1,
4,4,4,4,4,2,2,1,9,9,9,1,1,1,1,
4,4,2,4,4,2,1,1,9,1,9,1,1,9,1,
2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,9,1,1,
9,9,9,1,1,1,1,9,9,9,9,9,2,1,1,
```

Each horizontally or vertically contiguous grouping of digits corresponds to a particular polygon. For instance, the 9s form 5 distinct polygons, while the 4s form a single one.

[image]

I am attempting to programatically determine the vertices of these shapes. A pseudocode version of my algorithm would be:

```
foreach cell in the input
  if the cell has been visited
    continue
  else
    recursively add all neighbors that match the cell's digit to a list of cells
    when all neighbors have been added to the list, 
      find the top-most and then left-most cell. (I believe this is guaranteed to be a vertex)

      starting from the top-left corner of the cell, trace the polygon clockwise 
    endwhen
    set all cells in the list to "visited"'
endforeach
```

I have used this method successfully for simple polygons, both convex and concave, but there is one **major** flaw in this method -- it will *never* find holes in complex polygons.

I think I have determined an algorithm that will find the holes post-facto, but I thought I would take a step back and see if there wasn't a better, more-robust way of determining both vertices and holes simultaneously.

Any critiques / suggestions? Or am I on the right track, here?

Comment: Seems like holes begin when there is an overlap of three vertices. So from your list of vertices, begin at vertex with three duplicates, and trace around. Then you'll need to repeat the original process inside the hole, too. It might be easier to trace the complement of what you're looking for instead.

Comment: @DavidP 3 overlapping cell vertices just identifies a convex vertex, I believe. The 2 nestled among the 4s in my example data has 3 overlapping cell vertices, but is not actually part of a hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be much simpler than that, actually.

Add four boolean attributes for each cell, corresponding to the left, right, top, and bottom edges (*borders*). If the value in a cell differs from the value in a neighboring cell, then the border exists in the current cell.

If we visualize OP's data using this scheme, we get something like

```
   ▛▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▜▛▀▜▛▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▜▛▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▜
   ▌4  4  4  4  4  4  4▐▌2▐▌9  9  9▐▌1  1  1  1▐
   ▌              ▄▄▄▄▄▟▙▄▟▌       ▐▌          ▐
   ▌             ▐▛▀▀▀▀▜▛▀▜▌       ▐▌          ▐
   ▌4  4  4  4  4▐▌2  2▐▌1▐▌9  9  9▐▌1  1  1  1▐
   ▌     ▄▄▄     ▐▌  ▄▄▟▌ ▐▌  ▄▄▄  ▐▌     ▄▄▄  ▐
   ▌    ▐▛▀▜▌    ▐▌ ▐▛▀▀  ▐▌ ▐▛▀▜▌ ▐▌    ▐▛▀▜▌ ▐
   ▌4  4▐▌2▐▌4  4▐▌2▐▌1  1▐▌9▐▌1▐▌9▐▌1  1▐▌9▐▌1▐
   ▙▄▄▄▄▟▌ ▐▙▄▄▄▄▟▙▄▟▙▄▄  ▐▙▄▟▌ ▐▙▄▟▌  ▄▄▟▙▄▟▌ ▐
   ▛▀▜▛▀▜▌ ▐▛▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▜▛▀▜▌  ▀▀▀   ▀▀▀  ▐▛▀▜▛▀▀  ▐
   ▌2▐▌1▐▌2▐▌1  1  1▐▌2▐▌1  1  1  1  1▐▌9▐▌1  1▐
   ▙▄▟▙▄▟▙▄▟▌       ▐▙▄▟▙▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▟▙▄▟▌    ▐
   ▛▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▜▌        ▀▀▜▛▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▜▛▀▜▌    ▐
   ▌9  9  9▐▌1  1  1  1▐▌9  9  9  9  9▐▌2▐▌1  1▐
   ▙▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▟▙▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▟▙▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▟▙▄▟▙▄▄▄▄▟
```

If you implement a simple destructive walker, that can start at any given cell with one to four borders, consumes the borders it walks, and walks the region boundary in counterclockwise (or clockwise) order, you get exactly the polygons you want. Note that holes in polygons will then be drawn in the opposite order.

Note that you can use a double loop to examine each cell whether a walk should be started or not. The walker itself is a simple loop: if you walk the borders keeping the border on the right side (as if you kept your right hand on it), you are guaranteed to walk the boundary counterclockwise, and arrive at the point you started from. So, other than the edge information (4 bits per cell), no extra memory is needed.

Note the "rounded" corners. If you walk the regions counterclockwise, keeping the border on the right side, these occur when you arrive in a cell with no borders at all, and need to turn right (with respect to the direction you just walked). If you cannot turn right, the walk is complete.

(I used a small C program with wide-character output to draw the above Unicode diagram, just to verify the details, so this does work.)

---

Here is an example program, that reads a grid (of up to 252×252 cells) from standard input, accepting only decimal digits (0 to 9), and outputs an SVG image to standard output describing the grid, grid edges, and the polygons generated:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define   VALUE        15

#define   EDGE_TOP     16
#define   EDGE_RIGHT   32
#define   EDGE_BOTTOM  64
#define   EDGE_LEFT   128

#define   UP            0
#define   RIGHT         1
#define   DOWN          2
#define   LEFT          3

#ifndef   MAX_ROWS
#define   MAX_ROWS    254
#endif
#ifndef   MAX_COLS
#define   MAX_COLS    254
#endif
#ifndef   XSTEP
#define   XSTEP        32
#endif
#ifndef   YSTEP
#define   YSTEP        32
#endif

const char *svg_digit[16] = {
    "m0-8c-5 0-5 4-5 8s0 8 5 8 5-4 5-8 0-8-5-8z",
    "m-2-5 2-3v16",
    "m5+8h-10v-3c0-4 10-6 10-10 0-2-2-3-5-3s-5 1-5 3",
    "m-5+5c0 2 2 3 5 3s5-2 5-4c0 -3-2-4-5-4 3 0 5-1 5-4 0-2-2-4-5-4s-5 1-5 3",
    "m4-0h-9l7-8v16",
    "m5-8h-10v6c8 0 10 1 10 6 0 3-2 4-5 4-3 0-5-1-5-3",
    "m4-8c-8 0-8 8-8 11s1 5 4 5 4-2 4-4-1-4-4-4-4 2-4 4",
    "m-4-8h8v3s-4 7-4 13",
    "m-4-4c0-3 1-4 4-4s4 1 4 4c0 4-8 4-8 8 0 3 1 4 4 4s4-1 4-4c0-4-8-4-8-8z",
    "m-4+8c8 0 8-8 8-11s-1-5-4-5-4 2-4 4 1 4 4 4 4-2 4-4",
    "", "", "", "", "", ""
};

const char *svg_color[16] = {
    /* 0 */ "#000",
    /* 1 */ "#ff0000",
    /* 2 */ "#00ff00",
    /* 3 */ "#cccc00",
    /* 4 */ "#0000ff",
    /* 5 */ "#cc00cc",
    /* 6 */ "#00cccc",
    /* 7 */ "#999999",
    /* 8 */ "#ff9966",
    /* 9 */ "#6699ff",
    "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000", "#000"
};

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char cell[1+MAX_ROWS+1][1+MAX_COLS+1];
    int           rows = 0, cols = 0;
    int           row  = 1, col  = 1;
    int           ch;

    /* Clear grid. '0' is "outside". */
    memset(cell, 0, sizeof cell);

    /* Read decimal digit grid from standard input.
       For simplicity, the grid has one extra (empty, 0)
       cell around the actual data. */
    while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
        if (ch == '\n') {
            row++;
            col = 1;
            continue;
        } else
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            if (row <= MAX_ROWS && col <= MAX_ROWS)
                cell[row][col] = ch - '0';
            if (rows < row)
                rows = row;
            if (cols < col)
                cols = col;
            col++;
        }

    if (!rows || !cols) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No grid in standard input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (rows > MAX_ROWS || cols > MAX_COLS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Standard input grid is too large.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Define the edges. */
    for (row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
        for (col = 1; col <= cols; col++) {
            if ((cell[row][col] & VALUE) != (cell[row][col-1] & VALUE))
                cell[row][col] |= EDGE_LEFT;
            if ((cell[row][col] & VALUE) != (cell[row][col+1] & VALUE))
                cell[row][col] |= EDGE_RIGHT;
            if ((cell[row][col] & VALUE) != (cell[row-1][col] & VALUE))
                cell[row][col] |= EDGE_TOP;
            if ((cell[row][col] & VALUE) != (cell[row+1][col] & VALUE))
                cell[row][col] |= EDGE_BOTTOM;
        }

    /* Output an SVG image showing the outlines. */
    printf("<?xml version=\"1.1\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n");
    printf("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 %d %d\">\n",
                 (cols+2)*XSTEP, (rows+2)*YSTEP);

    /* White background rectangle. */
    printf("<rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"%dpx\" height=\"%dpx\" fill=\"#fff\" stroke=\"none\" />\n",
                 (cols+2)*XSTEP, (rows+2)*YSTEP);

    /* All values first. */
    printf("<path d=\"");
    for (row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
        for (col = 1; col <= cols; col++)
            printf("M %d%+d %s", col*XSTEP+XSTEP/2, row*YSTEP+YSTEP/2, svg_digit[cell[row][col] & VALUE]);
    printf("\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000\" stroke-width=\"1px\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" />\n");

    /* All edge segments. */
    printf("<path d=\"");
    for (row = 0; row <= rows + 1; row++)
        for (col = 0; col <= cols + 1; col++) {
            if (cell[row][col] & EDGE_TOP)
                printf("M %d,%d h %d", col*XSTEP+1, row*YSTEP+1, XSTEP-2);
            if (cell[row][col] & EDGE_BOTTOM)
                printf("M %d,%d h %d", col*XSTEP+1, (row+1)*YSTEP-2, XSTEP-2);
            if (cell[row][col] & EDGE_LEFT)
                printf("M %d,%d v %d", col*XSTEP+1, row*YSTEP+1, YSTEP-2);
            if (cell[row][col] & EDGE_RIGHT)
                printf("M %d,%d v %d", (col+1)*XSTEP-2, row*YSTEP+1, YSTEP-2);
        }
    printf("\" stroke=\"#000\" stroke-width=\"1px\" fill=\"none\" />\n");

    /* Walker start loop. Note that each closed loop must have at least one top edge. */
    for (row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
        for (col = 1; col <= cols; col++)
            if (cell[row][col] & EDGE_TOP) {
                const unsigned char v = cell[row][col] & VALUE;
                int                 r = row;
                int                 c = col;
                int                 d = RIGHT;

                printf("<path title=\"%d\" d=\"M %d %d", v, c*XSTEP, r*YSTEP);

                while (1)
                    if (d == RIGHT) { /* Top edge, right */
                        cell[row][col] &= ~EDGE_TOP;
                        printf(" h%+d", XSTEP);

                        if ((cell[row][col+1] & VALUE) == v &&
                            (cell[row-1][col+1] & VALUE) == v &&
                            cell[row-1][col+1] & EDGE_LEFT) {
                            --row;
                            ++col;
                            d = UP;
                        } else
                        if ((cell[row][col+1] & VALUE) == v &&
                            cell[row][col+1] & EDGE_TOP) {
                            ++col;
                            d = RIGHT;
                        } else
                        if (cell[row][col] & EDGE_RIGHT) {
                            d = DOWN;
                        } else
                            break;

                    } else
                    if (d == DOWN) { /* Right edge, down */
                        cell[row][col] &= ~EDGE_RIGHT;
                        printf(" v%+d", YSTEP);

                        if ((cell[row+1][col] & VALUE) == v &&
                            (cell[row+1][col+1] & VALUE) == v &&
                            cell[row+1][col+1] & EDGE_TOP) {
                            ++row;
                            ++col;
                            d = RIGHT;
                        } else
                        if ((cell[row+1][col] & VALUE) == v &&
                            cell[row+1][col] & EDGE_RIGHT) {
                            ++row;
                            d = DOWN;
                        } else
                        if (cell[row][col] & EDGE_BOTTOM) {
                            d = LEFT;
                        } else
                            break;

                    } else
                    if (d == LEFT) { /* Bottom edge, left */
                        cell[row][col] &= ~EDGE_BOTTOM;
                        printf(" h%+d", -XSTEP);

                        if ((cell[row][col-1] & VALUE) == v &&
                            (cell[row+1][col-1] & VALUE) == v &&
                            cell[row+1][col-1] & EDGE_RIGHT) {
                            ++row;
                            --col;
                            d = DOWN;
                        } else
                        if ((cell[row][col-1] & VALUE) == v &&
                            cell[row][col-1] & EDGE_BOTTOM) {
                            --col;
                            d = LEFT;
                        } else
                        if (cell[row][col] & EDGE_LEFT) {
                            d = UP;
                        } else
                            break;

                    } else
                    if (d == UP) { /* Left edge, up */
                        cell[row][col] &= ~EDGE_LEFT;
                        printf(" v%+d", -YSTEP);

                        if ((cell[row-1][col] & VALUE) == v &&
                            (cell[row-1][col-1] & VALUE) == v &&
                            cell[row-1][col-1] & EDGE_BOTTOM) {
                            --row;
                            --col;
                            d = LEFT;
                        } else
                        if ((cell[row-1][col] & VALUE) == v &&
                            cell[row-1][col] & EDGE_LEFT) {
                            --row;
                            d = UP;
                        } else
                        if (cell[row][col] & EDGE_TOP) {
                            d = RIGHT;
                        } else
                            break;

                    } else
                        break; /* Should never occur. */

                printf("z\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"%s\" opacity=\"0.5\" stroke-width=\"3px\" />\n", svg_color[v]);
            }

    printf("</svg>\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Using OP's example input, the resulting SVG image looks like this:
[image: Grid image]
If you open the SVG image in e.g. Inkscape, you can select and examine each individual polygon. The polygon outlines are thicker, with 50% opacity.

It is not difficult to see or prove that if there are $N$ cells, the above uses $O(N)$ space complexity (the `cell[][]` array; $4 N$ bits for the edge data), and $O(N)$ time complexity. (For the time complexity, note that in the `while` loop, each cell can be visited at most $4 N$ times, because each visit eliminates one edge.)

Comment: Your picture did not survive the transition to StackExchange in one piece, friend.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: That's because it's not a picture, it is Unicode "art" (as in ASCII art, except using the [Block Elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) unicode block). Copy and paste to a text editor, and switch to a better font (Courier New, Monospace, DejaVu Sans Mono). Now that SE no longer accepts http links to SVG images I store on my own site (and image servers mangle them into pixmap formats), that was the next-most-sensible format to have the test program output. I wouldn't bother drawing such images by hand... :)

Comment: Right -- I misunderstood your last sentence to imply your picture was supposed to be monospaced (instead of "this looks better monospaced"). I see now that pasting it into a text editor of my own renders it appropriately (though apparently Notepad++ refuses to render ▙,▛▟, and ▜)

Comment: The important takeaways I have from your answer: 1) You need edge data to fully determine the polygon, as a list of vertices isn't enough, and 2) I can construct that edge data when finding contiguous squares (the end list of which I don't otherwise need)

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Or, perhaps: 1) The edge data fully define all polygons (although you do need cell values to avoid joining vertex-connected polygons). 2) The edge data is trivial to construct using a single pass over the data. 3) A simple (destructive) edge walker can construct polygons with zero extra memory or backtracking needed. Your current implementation, you see, uses a lot of extra memory. 4) If the grid has N cells, then this leads to O(N) time complexity for finding all polygons -- with outlines drawn in one direction, and holes in the other.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Because me fail English often, I decided to edit my crude test program into an equally crude example, that takes in a grid formed by decimal digits (each digit 0 to 9 defining a grid cell, all other characters ignored), and outputs an SVG image to standard output. The image contains the cell values (in a single path), cell edges (also in a single path), and each polygon generated in separate paths, color depending on the cell value contained by the polygon.